# How to create a google maps like overlay in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When I am navigating on google maps and I click on the home button a small overlay appears on the home screen. I am trying to implement similar functionality in my flutter app want to know how I can go about doing the same

[overlay on home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61fkO.jpg)

Tried searching a bit but couldn't find where to start

Comment: if you find the answer useful please mark as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as pip i.e. Picture in picture mode.

You can use: [Flutter Picture  in Picture](https://pub.dev/packages/pip_flutter)